# Calculating the expectation in limiting case

Tags: integration, limits, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

I am interested in calculating the expectation of the following function:

$\log(1+xa)$ with respect to the random variable $x$, with distribution $f(x),x \in [0,\frac{1}{a}]$ when $a\to \infty$.

thus,

$\lim_{a \to \infty}\mathbb E[\log(1+ax)] = \lim_{a \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}} \log(1+xa)f(x)dx$

I can take the function inside the integral as $g(x,a)$. Thus I need to find the area of the curve $g(x,a)$ when a is very small. As per my understanding, as $\frac{1}{a} \to 0$, the area will become the realization of the function $g(x,a)$ at $0$(The area will become infinitesimally small, and thus the realization of the function at a given point).

thus $\lim_{a \to \infty}\mathbb E[\log(1+ax)] = g(0,a) = f(0)$. But this is not correct as the answer is given as $\mathbb P(x\leq \frac{1}{a})$.

Where did I go wrong in my understanding? How to achieve the correct answer?

Thank You!

Edit: If it helps then the distribution of $f(x) \sim \exp(1)$

Comment: It definitely helps that the distribution of $f$ is specified as the exponential distribution. Note that if $f$ changes, the answer to this question is expected to change as well.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I was under the impression that the way I am solving will give the answer $f(0)$ under all cases, but the final answer will obviously depend on what $f(.)$ is.

Comment: Actually, a question because I'm a little confused. So you are trying to calculate $\int_{0}^{\frac 1a} \log(1+xa) e^{-x}dx$ , if I'm not wrong? But then, you're taking the limit as $a$ is going to infinity, so how can the final answer depend upon $a$?

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer. In that case as we know the distribution of $x$ as $\exp(1)$ I can simply the final answer as $1/a = 0$. Actually, this is a part of a larger calculation and there are other expectation terms also. I am stuck in this particular expectation.

Comment: Ok, so let me try to understand this carefully. Actually, you're concerned with the limit $\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_0^{\frac 1a} \log(1+ax)f(x)dx$, and it turns out that you guessed the answer should be $f(0)$, when in fact for $f(x) = e^{-x}$ you're getting $0$ which isn't equal to $f(0)$ so you're asking (i) what's going wrong here and (ii) what is the answer to $\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_0^{\frac 1a} \log(1+ax)f(x)dx$ for a large class of $f$, is that right? In any case, I can't see how the answer is $P(X \leq \frac 1a)$ which depends on $a$.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer. (i) and (ii) are correct. Also, it is known that $P(X \leq 1/a)$ is the answer. Let me explain why it does not depend on a: As X is exponential I can write $P(X \leq 1/a)$ as $\int_0^{1/a} e^{-x} = 1-e^{-1/a}$ and for large value of a this will simplify to $1-(1-\frac{1}{a}) = 1/a = 0$

Comment: Sure, take your time. I'll register my interest and will answer this question once it's fully clear to me.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer, please check the updated comment.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do one thing. I'm still not fully sure about where $P(X \leq \frac 1a)$ comes from, but I can understand and give you an explanation for $(i)$ and $(ii)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question : Given $f: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$, what can be the nature of the limit $$
\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_0^\frac 1a \log(1+ax)f(x)dx
$$Must it exist? What can its values be?

---

Note that the limit and integral *cannot* be exchanged : the dominated convergence theorem doesn't apply (and using a partial converse of DCT from Brezis, it's possible to prove that the limit and integral exchange actually lead to different answers in some cases) because the function $\log(1+ax)f(x)$ is unbounded in $a$. This is why the argument presented in the original post fails.

If this could have been done, then the answer would have been expected as $f(0)$, as shown in the original post.

---

The usual way to get rid of this issue is to do an integration-by-parts. Let $g$ be any anti-derivative of $f$(assume that $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$). Note that we haven't specified $g$ at a point : so we know that the answer must not involve the value of $g$ at any point (but maybe a difference at two points). We have $$
\int_0^\frac 1a \log(1+ax)f(x)dx = \left[\log(1+ax)g(x)\right]^{\frac 1a}_{0} - \int_0^\frac 1a g(x) \frac{a}{1+ax} dx \\ = \ln(2)g\left(\frac 1a\right) - \int_0^{\frac 1a} \frac{ag(x)}{1+ax}dx
$$

where we can now focus on the RHS. Now, $g$ is continuous so the first term will go to $\log(2)g(0)$ as $a \to \infty$. The second term can be tackled using dominated convergence : which leads to the rigorous answer. For doing this, we write $$
\int_0^{\frac 1a} \frac{ag(x)}{1+ax}dx = \int_0^{1} \frac{g(x)}{\frac 1a+x}1_{[0,\frac 1a]}(x) dx 
$$
The pointwise limit of this quantity is $0$. Note that it is dominated by $\frac{g(x)}{x}$ for all $a$. However, if $\frac{g(x)}{x}$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ then we must have $g(0)=0$ (which shows that we have lost arbitrariness of the anti-derivative). Thus, the following result holds :

> If $f$ is an integrable function such that $\frac{g(x)}{x}$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ where $g$ is the integral of $f$ with $g(0)=0$, then $\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_0^{\frac 1a} \log(1+ax)f(x)dx = 0$.

This would capture many, many functions like constant $f$, or $f(x) = \frac 1{\sqrt x}$ and so on. It holds for $f(x) = e^{-x}$ as well : the antiderivative $g(x) = 1-e^{-x}$ is adjusted to give $g(0)=0$ , and $\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}$ is integrable on $[0,1]$.

You can use the above to prove the following :

> Suppose that $f$ is measurable and satisfies $\lim_{x \to 0} xf(x) = 0$. Then, $\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_0^{\frac 1a} \log(1+ax)f(x)dx = 0$.

---

However, here's a question : what happens if $f$ is on the edge of integrability, like say $f(x) = \frac 1x$, which is not integrable on $(0,1)$?

The answer for $f(x) = \frac 1x$ is itself quite interesting : the integral $$
\int_{0}^{\frac 1a} \frac{\log(1+ax)}{x}dx
$$
doesn't depend upon the value of $a$. To see this, perform the change of variable $Cu = x$ where $C$ is any positive constant, and get $$
\int_{0}^{\frac {1}{Ca}} \frac{\log(1+Cau)}{u/C}du/C = \int_{0}^{\frac {1}{b}} \frac{\log(1+bu)}{u}du
$$
where $b=Ca$. Since $C$ was arbitrary (positive), the answer is independent of $a$, and it will therefore equal the value for $a=1$, which is $\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}dx$, some positive quantity. (Turns out, it's $\pi^2/12$). With this and a simple use of the comparison principle, one can prove the following :

> Suppose that there exist constants $C_1,C_2$ such that $C_1<xf(x)<C_2$ for all $x \in [0,\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$. Then, $\lim_{a \to 0} \int_0^{\frac 1a} \log(1+ax)f(x)dx$ exists and is some positive constant.

What about $f$ going even slower? Once again, one can use a comparison principle (with the previous result) to see that if $xf(x)$ is unbounded in a neighborhood of $0$, then $\lim_{a \to 0} \int_0^{\frac 1a} \log(1+ax)f(x)dx$ is positive infinite.

Therefore, to summarize, the limit $\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\frac 1a} \log(1+ax)f(x)dx$

- is $0$ if $\lim_{x \to 0} xf(x) = 0$.
- is a positive finite quantity if $C_1<xf(x)<C_2$ for positive $C_1,C_2$ in a neighborhood of $0$.
- is $+\infty$ if $xf(x)$ is unbounded in a neighborhood of $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$\phi_a(x)=\mathbb{1}_{(0,1/a]}\log(1+ax), \qquad a>0$$

if $0<x<1/a$ then $1<1+ax<2$ and so, $0<\phi_a(x)\leq \log 2$ in $(0,1/a]$. Consequently
$|\phi_a|\leq\log2\mathbb{1}_{(0,1/a]}\leq\log2$

Notice $\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\phi_a(x)=0$ for all $x>0$.

The rest is dominated convergence:

$$\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}E[\phi_a(X)]=E[\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}\phi_a(X)]=0$$

or if dominated convergence is not within your grasp,
$$ E[\phi_a(X)]\leq\log2 P[X\leq1/a]\xrightarrow{a\rightarrow\infty}\log2 P[X=0]=0$$
since $X$ has a distribution that admits density.